# "Can only create NonNull of a Nullable GraphQLType but got: ID"

Tags: graphql-js

When running `apollo client:codegen` I get the following error:

```
  ✔ Loading Apollo Project
  ✖ Generating query files with 'typescript' target
    → Can only create NonNull of a Nullable GraphQLType but got: ID.
Error: Can only create NonNull of a Nullable GraphQLType but got: ID.
    at invariant (~/Code/humu/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:18:11)
    at new GraphQLNonNull (~/Code/humu/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:779:84)
    at Object.typeFromASTImpl (~/Code/humu/node_modules/graphql/utilities/typeFromAST.js:39:25)
    at variables.map.node (~/Code/humu/node_modules/apollo-codegen-core/lib/compiler/index.js:73:36)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Compiler.compileOperation (~/Code/humu/node_modules/apollo-codegen-core/lib/compiler/index.js:71:75)
    at Object.compileToIR (~/Code/humu/node_modules/apollo-codegen-core/lib/compiler/index.js:15:44)
    at Object.generate [as default] (~/Code/humu/node_modules/apollo/lib/generate.js:78:36)
    at write (~/Code/humu/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:67:54)
    at Task.task (~/Code/humu/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:86:46)
```

Why is this happening? The error sounds as if the schema has two non-null operators (eg: `ID!!`) or similar, but in my schema file I don't have that.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that you have two different versions of `graphql-js` loaded into memory. Internally, the package does an `instanceof` check to determine if something is a valid GraphQL type, and if an object is passed from one copy to the other, the check will incorrectly return false.

Our team ran into this problem and were able to fix it with a [yarn resolution](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/):

```
// in package.json
"resolutions": {
  "graphql": "14.3.1"
}
```

(Also: it turns out that yarn 1.x [has a bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5039#issuecomment-466263012) where resolutions aren't respected when running `yarn add`. Running just `yarn` fixes it.)